# move DOM HTML element around

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to move the div `"ARTEFACT1"` around. I tried to do that with the function of jQuery but it doesn't work.

Here is the jsfiddle.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xrekvem1/1)

Comment: Please include your code in the question also.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to 
use [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

You'll need to install [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/).

There are some samples on the Draggable link.

Also, you can achive this with much less codes. You have used multiple class attr in one div and some of the classes are not useful as you have set the same ID for the Class.

Maybe use one class for all your draggable divs and different IDs.